# How to split this line?

Tags: c#, split

I'm trying to split this string line:

```
"\"Language\" \"english\""
```

the line comes from this text:

```
"Language" "english"
```

while reading from a txt file.

I've tried this:

```
string[] allParts = line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Where `line` is the var containing the string above. What I've tried gives me back the following array:

[image]

But I want both strings to be splitted, and I can't remove the `"\` from it, and it fails in another place where I need only the string. Any idea on how can I achieve this?

I would like this output:

```
allParts[0] --> "Language" 
allParts[1] --> "english"
```

Comment: so what output would you like? I think you want to do more than just split.

Comment: `line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\\', '\"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`; I can't tell if you are confused by the debugger or the escape character but this expression covers the angles. If you need to handle spaces in strings then split is not what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **content** of your string actually is `"Language" "english"`!

There are no back slashes. The **debugger window** displays back slashes because it displays the **string literal** as you would write it in your code:

```
string s = "\"Language\" \"english\"";
```

Here you use the backslashes to escape the quotes (`"`). Simply split your string by a white space:

```
string[] parts = s.Split(' ');
```

and your resulting strings will be `"Language"` and `"english"` (including those double quotes).

---

If you output the parts in a console (`Console.WriteLine(parts[0]);`) you'll see this output:

```
"Language"
"english"
```

If you want to get rid of the `"` you can simply trim the strings:

```
string part0 = parts[0].Trim('"');
string part1 = parts[1].Trim('"');
```

If you output `part0` and `part1` now you get this output:

```
Language
english
```

---

You can combine these two steps like this:

```
string[] parts = s.Split(' ').Select(p => p.Trim('"')).ToArray();
```

Comment: It's supposed to do that, but actually it's not working... I use the same code and still has this weird behaviour...

Comment: Yes, if you write it it ignores the slash, but when you compare it to another string, it fails...

Comment: That last solution solved my problem! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Just `Trim` the `"`

```
string[] trimmedParts = allParts.Select(p => p.Trim('\"')).ToArray();
```

Or combined with your code:

```
string[] allParts = line
    .Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(p => p.Trim('\"')).ToArray();
```

If your terms can contain spaces too, I'd recommend this approach instead:

```
string[] allParts = line
    .Split(new []{'\"'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(p => ! String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
    .Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();
```

If your terms can contain spaces and escaped quotes too, you need to update your question ;)

[DotNetFiddle Demos](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jKMSf5)

Comment: if input is `"\"Language\" \"english  df\"";` then this will not work

Comment: Yeah, "if". "If" that is the case, the question is incomplete ;)

Comment: Think Twice, Code Onces

Answer (score 1):

USE:

```
 string[] allParts = line.Split(new string[]{ "\" \"", "\""  },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This would give expected result

Comment: if input is "\"Language\" \"english df\""; then this will not work

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = "\"Language\" \"english lan\"";
var repStr = data.Split(new char[] { '\"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
if (repStr != null)
{ 
    var result = repStr.ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: if input is "\"Language\" \"english df\""; then this will not work

Comment: @PranavPatel I made the change. may be it better than accepted one

Comment: bro insted of this `"\""` use `'\"'`

Comment: @PranavPatel  thanks for your helps. I have changed that.